# What is the simplist way of assigning a dynamic variable based upon a dynamic variable?

Tags: bash

Here is my code:

```
$ abc_1='hello world'
$ abc_2='now is the time'
$ for i in {1..2}; do var=abc_$i;echo ${!var}; done
```

Output:
hello world
now is the time

How do I combine the two do loop inner statements into a simpler and more efficient one?

I've tried the following without success:

```
echo ${!abc_$i}  
echo ${!{abc_$i}}  
echo ${!abc_${i}}  
echo ${!abc_!{$i}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Bash does not support computed variables like `${abc_${def}}`.  The indirect variable feature works with full variables only. As in, the full contents of a variable and only those contents being interpreted as the name of another variable. This is a feature imitated from the Korn shell.

Comment: Therefore, there is no way to calculate the name of a variable as a complex string operation, without using `eval`.

Comment: by the way, I think the moment you need this might be the moment you let go of your shell and went for a richer programming language. Say, Python, Ruby, Go, C++… whatever gloats your goat!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, maybe `tcl` can simplify the code even more

Comment: I've worked with FPGA toolchains too much; tcl is definitely something that frightens me now ;)

Comment: Don't use variable indirection, use an array instead.  It's not uncommon for people to think that indirection is the solution to a problem - in almost all cases they are wrong and indirection becomes the cause of many other problems. BTW, I agree with @MarcusMüller's suggestion of using a better language but would add perl to the list - it is designed to be an upgrade to basic shell scripting and includes improved versions of all the features of shell, sed, awk, grep, tr and more built-in (but without shell's whitespace/quoting issues) plus has access to tens of thousands of library modules.

Comment: Agreeing with cas, I guess as usual. By Larry Wall's colorful cloak, PERL is an option, but as I discussed on a bus with him (nice guy), it might just be a bit too syntactically rich for its own good. (Also, I did not realize who I'm discussing with, and he really is a nice guy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear, just don't. If you have data that's indexed by a number, use an array, same as you do in any programming language:

```
arr=('hello world' 'now is the time')
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf "element at index %s is '%s'\n" "$i" "${arr[i]}"
done
```

If you have data that's indexed by strings, use an associative array.

See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 1):

My code become a bit ugly but here it is:

```
for i in {1..2}; do var="abc_$i";echo $(eval echo \$$var); done
```

The idea is to create the variable names and the use `eval` to `echo` the variables. You need backslash otherwise the variable `$$` is interpreted.

P.S. Maybe will be wise to consider use of arrays.

Comment: I'd like to give this +1, and give ilkkachu's answer +1.5 …

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the original code is still simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @analytical, I do not get it what you mean by original code. If this is the code in the question it does not work.

Comment: The original code works with two statements: one assignment and one echo where as your code uses four statements: one assignment, one eval and two echos.

Comment: @analytical, I do not get it, what you want, simple code which do not work or more complex code which do the work?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov - As previously stated, the original code works with the two inner statements as is. Try it for yourself. To clarify, I tried to combine the two inner statements into one without success, thus the reason for my request for help.